# Is there an easy way in C++ to round to the nearest 1.75 increment

Tags: c++, rounding

I tried looking up this on StackOverflow, close this question if this has been answered already. But is there a function in C++ that can round a value to an increment with a decimal value? Please generalize your answer for any given decimal increment - I would like to also know, for example, how to round to the nearest 1.78 increment.

Comment: int n -= % 1.75; this would subtract the result of the modulo operator (remainder), which will always give you an easily dividable solution.; if you want to round up, you can calculate n -= ( %n > 0.5*1.75 ?  %n : (-1) * %n );

Comment: `1.75 * std::round(n / 1.75)`

Comment: @SeanBrookins what you have written is not C++ at all.  You've mixed inplace decrement with an assignment statement and modulo operator with a double value for integer storage.  Not really sure what a compiler would tell you if it encountered that.

Comment: I discussed pseudo code in a code comment. If I had submitted it as an answer, your comment might be <helpful isn't the right word... just don't know what is>, but my goal was instead to briefly detail two logical approaches as possible starting points. @paddy

Answer (score 4):

There is no specific function to do that, but you can easily make one.  Just divide the value by 1.75, then call `std::round` and then multiply by 1.75.

*e.g.*

```
double round_to_multiple(double val, double step)
{
    return step * std::round(val / step);
}
```

Where "step" is the step-size, or multiple.  In your case, 1.75.

Just be wary of floating-point rounding error.  If you are always dealing with 2 decimal places and the numbers you work with are in a useful range, you might want to consider using integers instead (multiplied by 100), which would change the technique a little.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "step"?

Comment: Step would be 1.75 or 1.78

Comment: My mistake.  I thought it was obvious.  I have edited the answer to spell it out.

Comment: So for example, if my value is 3.86, then val is: 3.86/1.75 = 2.205714... . And then step = 1.75. So then the inputs to that function is round_to_multiple(2.205714, 1.75). Correct?

Comment: What?  No!  `round_to_multiple(3.86, 1.75)`.  Don't you see what this simple function is doing?

Comment: My bad - I'm not a mathemagician. It's hard for me to understand how you derived that equation. Thanks for the response!

Comment: That's why I also explained the operation in the first paragraph before showing it in generalized form as a function.